# Why does my reg ex not capture 2nd and subsequent lines?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match

**Update**

I tried adding [RegexOptions.Singleline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Singleline) to my `regex` options. It worked in that it captured the lines that weren't previously captured, but it put the entire text file into the first match instead of creating one match per date as desired.

**End of Update**

**Update #2**

Added new output showing matches and groups when using Poul Bak's modification. See screen shot below titled **Output from Poul Bak's modification**

**End of Update #2**

**Final Update**

Updating the target framework from 4.6.1 to 4.7.1 and tweaking Poul Bak's `reg ex` a little bit solved all problems. See Poul Bak's answer below

**End of Final Update**

**Original Question: Background**

I have the following text file `test_text.txt`:

```
2018-10-16 12:00:01 - Error 1<CR><LF>
   Error 1 text line 1<CR><LF>
   Error 1 text line 2<CR><LF>
2018-10-16 12:00:02 AM - Error 2<CR><LF>
   Error 2 text line 1<CR><LF>
   Error 2 text line 2<CR><LF>
   Error 2 text line 3<CR><LF>
   Error 2 text line 4<CR><LF>
2018-10-16 12:00:03 PM - Error 3
```

**Objective**

My objective is to have each match be comprised of 3 `named` groups: Date, Delim, and Text as shown below.

*Note: apostrophes used only to denote limits of matched text.*

**Matches I expect to see:**

```
Match 1: '2018-10-16 12:00:01 - Error 1<CR><LF>'
   Date group = '2018-10-16 12:00:01'
   Delim group = ' - '
   Text group = 'Error 1<CR><LF>Error 1 text line 1<CR><LF>Error 1 text line 2<CR><LF>'

Match 2: '2018-10-16 12:00:02 AM - Error 2<CR><LF>'
   Date group = '2018-10-16 12:00:02 AM'
   Delim group = ' - '
   Text group = 'Error 2 text line 1<CR><LF>Error 2 text line 2<CR><LF>Error 2 text line 3<CR><LF>Error 2 text line 4<CR><LF>'

Match 3: `2018-10-16 12:00:03 PM - Error 3`
   Date group = '2018-10-16 12:00:03 PM'
   Delim group = ' - '
   Text group = 'Error 3'
```

**The problem**

My regex is not working in that 2nd and subsequent lines of text (e.g., 'Error 1 text line 1', 'Error 2 text line 1') are not being captured. I expect them to be captured because I'm using the `Multiline` option.

How do I modify my regex to capture 2nd and subsequent lines of text?

**Current code**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp_RegEx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\bill\Desktop\test_text.txt");
            string pattern = @"(?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*)(?<Delim>\s-\s)(?<Text>.*\n|.*)";

            RegexOptions regexOptions = (RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, regexOptions);
            MatchCollection ms = rx.Matches(text);

            // Find matches.
            MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

            Console.WriteLine("Input Text\n--------------------\n{0}\n--------------------\n", text);

            // Report the number of matches found.
            Console.WriteLine("Output ({0} matches found)\n--------------------\n", matches.Count);

            int m = 1;

            // Report on each match.
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Match #{0}: ", m++, match.Value);

                int g = 1;
                GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;

                foreach (Group group in groups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   Group #{0} {1}", g++, group.Value);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**Current Output**

[image]

**Output from Poul Bak's modification (on the right track, but not quite there yet)**

`@"(?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\s\w\w)?)(?<Delim>\s-\s)(?<Text>([\s\S](?!\d{4}))*)"`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex, modified from yours:

```
@"(?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\s\w\w)?)(?<Delim>\s-\s)(?<Text>([\s\S](?!\d{4}))*)"
```

I have changed the `'Date'` Group so it accepts `'AM'` or `'PM'` (otherwise it will only match the first).

Then I have changed the `'Text'` Group, so it matches any number of any char (including Newlines) until it `looks forward` and finds a new date.

**Edit**:

I don't understand it, when you say `'AM'` and `'PM'` are not matched, they are part of the `'Date'` Group. I assume you want them to be part of the `'Delim'` Group, so I have moved the check to that Group.

I have also changed a Group to a non capturing Group.

The new regex:

```
 @"(?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(?<Delim>(?:\s\w\w)?\s-\s)(?<Text>(?:[\s\S](?!\d{4}))*)"
```

BTW: You should change your code for checking Groups, like this:

```
        foreach (Group group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   Group #{0} {1}", group.Name, group.Value);
        }
```

Then you will see your `named Groups` by `Name` and `Value`. When you have named Groups, there's no need for accessing by index.

**Edit** 2:

About 'group.Name': I had mistakenly used 'Group' (capitalized), it should be: 'group.Name'.

This is what the regex look like now:

```
@"(?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\s\w\w)?)(?<Delim>\s-\s)(?<Text>(?:[\s\S](?!\d{4}))*)"
```

I suggest you set the '`RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`' flag, then you only get named groups.

Comment: Thank-you for the effort. Your regex is definitely capturing 2nd and subsequent lines, but the text following the date can be ' - ', ' AM - ', or ' PM - ' and your regex loses that piece, Also, your regex is creating many unwanted groups. See the screen shot in my answer titled **Output from Poul Bak's modification**. I'm examining your regex to see which part I need to retain in order to get the 2nd and subsequent lines

Comment: My mistake! For AM, PM, or neither, your original regex was correct. My eyes just missed it. However, the problem still remains: your regex creates many unwanted groups. Compare the output labled **Output from Poul Bak's modification** with the output my expected output labeled **Matches I expect to see:**. Also: When I have the debugger on, I see the `Name` property in the `group` object, but when I try to add 'Console.WriteLine("   Group #{0} {1}", group.Name, group.Value);', the compiler says '`Group does not contain a definition for 'Name'`. I don't get it - - the property is there

Comment: Just to be clear: the `(?<Text>(?:[\s\S](?!\d{4}))*)` portion of your regex solved the heart of my problem

Comment: Figured out the `group.name` issue. Needed to up my target framework from 4.6.1 to 4.7.1

Comment: Changing the target framework to 4.7.1 also resulted in many of the unwanted groups to disappear. By changing the `looks forward` to look for an entire date, the rest of them went away: `@"(?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\s\w\w)?)(?<Delim>\s{1}-\s{1})(?<Text>(?:[\s\S](?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))*)";`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the many Groups (using 4.7.2). Didn't know they had changed something. So I learned something too.